# Post-Request of Xamarin App is not working on newer Samsung Smartphones

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, http-post

on newer Samsung Smartphones like the Galaxy S9, S9+, S10, s10+ or google Pixel my post request to login fails. The weird thing is it only fails when im not connected to the Wifi. It seems like something blocks the Request from getting sent. 
When I debug my App it says "one or more errors occured trying to send the Request"
It does work on my Galaxy A8 (Android 9) or Galaxy S7 (Android 8)

My HttpCLient:

```
private HttpClient LoginClient()
    {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sollevaapi.ctl.de/")
        };

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    return httpClient;
    }
```

The Request:

```
 HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;
            try
                {
                httpResponse = client.PostAsync("Token", content).Result;
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                var WebEx = ex.InnerException.InnerException as WebException;
                if (WebEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure)
                    {
                    throw new Exception("Die Web-API ist nicht unter sollevaapi.ctl.de erreichbar!", ex);
                    }
                throw;
                }
```

Comment: Update: It only doesnt work with "Telekom" as mobile data provider. How is this possible?

Comment: Does other app work properly with "Telekom" as mobile data provider?

Comment: It seems like Telekom has some routing issues with ipv6

Comment: Yeah, I think this problem is not caused by your code too.